# geocomplete_rails and Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to use geocomplete_rails gem: https://github.com/guyisra/geocomplete_rails

My `application.js` file looks like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require moment
//= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
//= require geocomplete
//= require_tree .

$(function() {
  $('#event_raw_location').geocomplete();
});
```

When I open form page with `#event_raw_location` element, I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined` error and autocomplete does not work. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation in [here](http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/) it looks like you should add one more JavaScript.

Try adding following line in your *app/views/layouts/application.html.erb*:

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;libraries=places"></script>
```

before line:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes, just found it out :), but this `&amp;` caused another problems, I chaneg it for `&` and now it all works fine.